# What is causing segmentation fault in subset sum problem, dynamic programmng standard code?

Tags: segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Subset sum problem: Given a set of numbers, check whether it can be partitioned into two subsets such that the sum of elements in both subsets is same or not.

here is the standard bottom-up method of dynaic programming, this is causing segmentation fault when multiple test cases are passed

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int subset(int sum,int n,int num[]){
    if(sum%2!=0)return 0;
    int dp[n+1][sum+1];
    for(int i =0;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<=sum;j++){
            if(i==0||j==0)dp[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(int i =1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j =1;j<=sum;j++){
            if(num[i-1]>j)
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
            else if(num[i-1]==j)
                dp[i][j] = 1;
            else 
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j],dp[i-1][j-num[i-1]]);
            //cout<<dp[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        //cout<<endl;
    }
    return dp[n][sum/2];
}

int main() {
    int t;cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n,sum=0;cin>>n;
        int num[n];
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
            int x;cin>>x;
            sum+=x;
            num[i] = x;
        }
        //cout<<sum<<endl;
        if(subset(sum,n,num)==1)
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you learn about the problem by using a debugger?

Comment: I don't have access to a debugger..